# Passing argument to a ReadP Parser in Haskell

Tags: parsing, haskell, functional-programming, monads

I am trying to create a parser from scratch in Haskell. I have problems passing a string as an argument to a function that is already part of a do block in which the parsing occurs. Why does the following Minimal viable example code return `[]` and not `4` as expected.

```
import Data.Char
import Text.ParserCombinators.ReadP
import Control.Applicative ((<|>))

type Parser a = ReadP a 

token :: Parser a -> Parser a
token combinator = (do spaces
                       combinator)

space :: Parser Char
space = satisfy isSpace

spaces :: Parser String 
spaces = many space

parseString input = readP_to_S (do                         
                        e <- pExpr
                        token eof
                        return e) input
                  
pExpr = (do            
            pv <- pOpHelper
            spaces            
            str <- string pv
            return str            
        )

pOpHelper :: Parser String 
pOpHelper = (do         
        e1 <- munch isDigit
        return e1
        )
```

I am of course interested in returning a processed version of whatever `string pv` returns. However I can't understand why the current setup wouldn't return anything besides `[]` on `parseString "4"` since calling just `pOpHelper` wihtout pExpr seems to work.

**Edit**

I think I have located the 'bug' to be part of the `string` function. I had a closer look at it [here](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.17.0.0/docs/Text-ParserCombinators-ReadP.html) but I can't see from the documentation why it shouldn't work in the above. But the above code is narrowed down to the parts that produce the unintended outputs as specified.

**EDIT EDIT**
I have now narrowed the problem down even further. It has to do with how 'consumption' works for the parser. The problem is that if I give it `parseString "4"` the `string pv` expects the "4" that is returned by pv, but it will still be parsing the next characters on which `munch isDigit` is no longer satisfies. This means that it will only return `[("4","")]` rather than `[]` if the input is `parseString "4 4"`, and only if the `spaces` has been added to the `do`-clause in `pExpr`.

But how can I work around this and avoid 'consuming' the string that I put as input. Is there a way to use `look` for instance, in the above documentation.

As pointed out in the comments below I am interested in transforming whatever is the input to `pOpHelper` and then passing its output to functions (in a recursion) that is part of the parent parser-function called. But how can I do it without consuming the input with `pOpHelper` first such that the following example would return `str` on input of `"4"`:

```
pExpr = (do            
            pv <- pOpHelper
            --spaces            
            str <- string pv 
            if str == "(4)" then return str -- do stuff!
            else pfail
            
        )

pOpHelper :: Parser String 
pOpHelper = (do      
        
        e1 <- munch isDigit
        return ( "(" ++ e1 ++ ")" )
        )
```

Comment: `pOpHelper` munches digits until there are no more digits, then `string` tries to read the same string that pOpHelper just returned.

Comment: Yes, I just realized. And I am currently editing the post with that update, and my updated question as well: How do I work around that.

Comment: Just ditch `string`.

Comment: But what I want to accomplish however, is that I wan't to make transformation to whatever is returned by `pOpHelper`, such as for instance a parenthesis around like `(++ pv ++)` an the resulting expression I want to evaluate with another function as if it was a string that was passed to the latter. The intention is to use this in a recursive function that I want to be left associative, such that I can call what ever `pOpHelper` returns with several parsing functions.